# How to Automate the process of certifying the devices connecting to AWS IOT Core - JITR

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, iot, aws-iot, aws-iot-core

My goal is to build an IoT solution, Where I have `device -> AWS IOT Core(mqtt) -> AWS IOT Analytics -> WebApplication (Dashboard)`

My question is related to this stage `device -> AWS IOT Core(mqtt)`, is there a way to automate the process of authenticating a device to have access to AWS IoT Core?

With some search I found that there's something called Just In Time Registration (JITR) for activating the device certificate. I had a look at the blog (https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/iot/just-in-time-registration-of-device-certificates-on-aws-iot/).

I'm wondering how JITR would help me to automate the process? Would I use the SDK for creating the certificates and signing them? The article is too vague to me and I'm a beginner at AWS.

Comment: Please use English in the title as well

Comment: Authenticating how? Don't you first create a `thing` in IOT Core representing your devices and get the certificates? The certificates authenticate your devices. Not sure what other authentication do you expect?

Comment: @Marcin I don't intend to certify more than 1000 devices manually from the console, I only need to automate this process.

Comment: You can create one `thing` and reuse its certs across all devices, can't you?